# What are your top Visual Studio 2010 extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, add-in

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Best VS2010 Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646154/best-vs2010-extensions)
>   [Visual Studio 2010 - recommended extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757357/visual-studio-2010-recommended-extensions)

I've just discovered [JSEnhancements](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/0696ad60-1c68-4b2a-9646-4b5f4f8f2e06) for Visual Studio 2010 and it's left me wondering what other "indispensable" extensions and add-ins there are that I might benefit from.

What are your key productivity extensions for Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: DAMMIT! I promise I did a search before creating this question and I didn't find that article.  I'll vote to close this one.  Sorry, all.

Comment: See also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960793/what-are-the-best-visual-studio-extensions

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757357/visual-studio-2010-recommended-extensions

Answer (score 3):

**[JetBrains Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)**. It's not free, but it's surely the best around.

**Edit**: I also like **[TestDriven.NET](http://www.testdriven.net/)**. And it's usually free.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the much-publicised VS Power Productivity Tools?  How does the latest version of Resharper compare?

Comment: +1 Also don't forget that ReSharper its self also has tons of plugins.

Comment: @Phil: I've been using ReSharper for 3 major versions now (4.0, 4.5, 5.0 for VS2010), and I don't think there's anything close to it. 

I really don't like to compare R# with the productivity tools as I don't even see overlapping features between them. That said, I have the biggest respect for the Productivity Tools because a) they're not charging crazy money like R# and b) Mr. ASP.NET himself (Scott Gu) endorses it --> http://bit.ly/agjhOM