# visual studio 2012 addon for line numbers and exception management?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, add-on

I'm looking for FREE (or cheap) addons to visual studio 2012 to:

- add line numbers to a procedure, class or entire project
- add exception management to a code block or sub (parametrized exception code if possible)

I'm using mz-tools for both things on visual studio 2010, but the mz-tools license i have won't upgrade to the visual studio 2012 and i don't want to pay another $70 for 2 functions (i'm noy using other mz-tools tools)

thank you very much!

Update:

I don't want to see the file line numbers, I want to see the code-in line numbers, like those:

```
20:         Dim sw As IO.StreamWriter = IO.File.AppendText(".\debug.log")
30:         Dim s As String

40:         s = DateTime.Now.ToString 

50:         sw.Write(s)
60:         sw.WriteLine()
70:         sw.Close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Line Numbers can already be seen if you go to

> Tools --> Options -- > Text Editor (on the left hand pane) -->All Languages

Now you would find a small check box saying `Line Numbers` on the right hand side in the Display group.Check it off to get line numbers on your source code.

**Edit**

This is in VS 2010 Ultimate.

**Second Edit:**

This is what I see in my end:

[image: Line Numbers]

Isn't this the same thing which you're asking?

**Third Update**:

Okay now I get it! I hope [the links here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646154/best-vs2010-extensions) would help you.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! I've expressed myself wrong; I don't want to "see" the actual line numbers, I want to specify the code-in lines, I don't know how to describe it, so I update my question with an example. Regards!

Comment: No, it's not what i want... i also have those line numbers, but those i can't use with the ERL function. Check this: http://i50.tinypic.com/2cpcldy.png